# unity admob click count setting works 1 time

Tags: admob

Now every time user clicks next button, interstitial ads show itself. but of course as you might know, it is very annoying.

I dont know how to count how many times users press the restart button and for example show the ads every 3 or 4 times if user press the button.

```
public void ShowInterstitialAd()
{
    if (counter == 2)
    {

        Debug.Log("Showing interstitial ad.");
        if (_interstitialAd != null && _interstitialAd.CanShowAd())
        {
            _interstitialAd.Show();
            
        }
        counter = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;  

    }
}
```